Why weak_ptr::use_count may return a different count to shared_ptr::use_count?
The cppreference.com's entry on weak_ptr::use_count includes the caveat:

The usage and behavior of this function are similar to std::shared_ptr::use_count, but it returns a different count.

Since it's supposed to count how many shared_ptr instances share ownership of the pointer, under which circumstances could it return a different count?

Clumsy phrasing? Don't forget it's a wiki. Prior to the most recent edit of that page (which changed this particular sentence), it mentioned something about potential race conditions.

in reality all implementations just calls the same function that shared_ptr does

Is there a public getter for the weak use count?  (I imagine it'd only be useful for debugging.)

maybe the note tries to say that what is returned is not the count of the shared_ptr you created the weak_ptr from. That wouldnt work because when the shared_ptr is gone, the weak ptrs count is still 0. I dont know. I mean the same cpprref page says twice that its the number of shared ptrs, you go to docs for shared_ptr::count it says the same ...

The count may be cached and not updated if the backing shared_ptr has been deleted. (I would never use use_count on either type in production code at all)

The text in the c++ standard draft is:

long use_count() const noexcept;

Returns: 0 if *this is empty; otherwise, the number of shared_ptr instances that share ownership with *this.

I suppose, what the note tries to say is that weak_ptr::use_count cannot simply return the value of the std::shared_ptrs count from which it was created. When all shared pointers are gone, std::weak_ptr::use_count can still be called and returns 0.
Don't forget that cppreference is a wiki, it is community curated. Usually it is rather close to the text in the standard. I didn't find anything similar to this note in the standard though.

yeah, I'm sure that part could be better worded
